# Search of optimal algorithm to find a point in 2D plane, whose inclusion maximizes the area of new voronoi region

Tags: python, algorithm, math, scipy, voronoi

I am working with Voronoi diagrams limited to a section of plane (so that I can measure areas of regions, and they don't go off to infinity), and I'm considering only integer co-ordintes in this exercise.

Here's the problem: 
**I have an existing Voronoi tessellation and I want to add a new point (xi, yi) such that the new region created by this point has the maximum possible area.**

Now, what I came up with was a brute force solution, which will run for each possible point (considering integers only), and calculate area of new region.

I wrote the code in python and here is one example I tested: 
I have 5 vertices: `[[-5,  7], [ 2,  5], [-6, -2], [ 7,  2], [-4,  6]]` and their Voronoi tessellation is (numbers in red denote area of that region):

[image: voronoi example]

I tried brute force approach for vertices in range [-5,5) along X-axis and [-5,5) along Y-axis, and calculated that with vertex `(1, -5)` we get maximum possible area: `47.81`

[image]

I tried to search a lot on how to optimize my approach further from brute force, but couldn't find any direction.
Could someone kindly guide me on the mathematical and programming strategies to address this problem? Any insights would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You seem to have an extra constraint, that you only calculate the areas inside the given rectangle (otherwise most areas would be infinitive). Is the new point allowed to be outside the rectangle? Do you only consider integer coordinates? Maybe you could try some hill-climbing approach. Choose a starting point at random, then test some small step from there in some random directions and step in the "best" direction until no progress is made. Then repeat with other starting points. The vertices of the old voronoi tessellation could be good starting points.

Comment: I suggest you post the 'brute force' code you used. The area of the new point's region  may vary discontinuously as it moves around so a calculus based approach might not be fruitful. Also, you're only wanting integer coordinates, so I think trying all points may be your best bet if you want to be sure of a global maximum.There's a lot of computation that could be done just once, such as finding the equations of the lines of equidistant points, but if whatever library you're using doesn't provide the functionality you want, you may need to re-code a lot of it to get to the internals of it all.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to - instead of considering each possible allowed point as a candidate for the new point and calculating the area for each of those precisely (which would be the naive brute-force approach, most definitely infeasible for any reasonably "large" planes/grids) - simply choose granularity levels for which you deem the trade-off between runtime and accuracy/optimality of results to be good.

The following code allows to control both the sparsity of the candidates to consider for the new point (controllable via the parameter `alpha`, meaning considering only pixels at indices divisible by `alpha`, e.g. `alpha=1` means every pixel is considered, `alpha=2` means only a quarter of the pixels are considered, etc.) as well as the granularity of the area calculation (controllable via the parameter `beta`, meaning only using pixels at indices divisible by `beta` to assign to clusters for the purpose of area calculation, e.g. `beta=1` would give full precision). I.e. higher values give worse but faster results. The algorithm simply picks whichever candidate point results in the highest area (approximated as the share of pixels assigned to it).

```
from random import randint, seed
import time
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.spatial import ConvexHull


def get_points(min_d, max_d, min_np, max_np):
    h = randint(min_d, max_d)
    w = randint(min_d, max_d)
    nd = randint(min_np, max_np)
    points = []
    while len(points) < nd:
        i = randint(0, h)
        j = randint(0, w)
        if (i, j) not in points:
            points.append((i, j))
    return h, w, points


def best_new_point(h, w, points, alpha, beta):
    cands = {(i, j) for i in range(0, h, alpha) for j in range(0, w, alpha)} - set(points)
    pixs = {(i, j) for i in range(0, h, beta) for j in range(0, w, beta)}
    
    best = None
    area = -1
    for cand in cands:
        areas = {k: set() for k in points}
        areas[cand] = set()
        for ij in pixs:
            f = lambda xy: (xy[0] - ij[0]) ** 2 + (xy[1] - ij[1]) ** 2
            k = min(areas.keys(), key=f)
            areas[k].add(ij)
        if len(areas[cand]) > area:
            best = cand
            area = len(areas[cand])
    return best

def draw_voronoi(h, w, points):
    img = np.zeros((h, w))
    areas = {k: set() for k in points}
    inds = {(i, j) for i in range(h) for j in range(w)}
    for ij in inds:
        f = lambda xy: (xy[0] - ij[0]) ** 2 + (xy[1] - ij[1]) ** 2
        k = min(points, key=f)
        areas[k].add(ij)
    for c, p in enumerate(points):
        area = areas[p]
        for i, j in area:
            img[i, j] = c
    return img
```

For the sake of demonstration, the additional constraint of "integer coordinates" is ignored (as the adaptation should be straight-forward & that wasn't what I wanted to focus on here), and only a small number of points as well as only a small plane is considered.

```
seed(69)
dim = 128
nd = 4
h, w, points = get_points(dim, dim, nd, nd)
img = draw_voronoi(h, w, points)
for i, j in points:
    img[i, j] = nd+1
plt.imshow(img);
plt.scatter([y for x, y in points], [x for x, y in points], **{'c': 'black', 's': 12});

plt.subplots_adjust(left=0, right=1, top=1, bottom=0, wspace=0, hspace=0)
plt.axis('off')
plt.show()
```

The original voronoi diagram looks as follows:

[image: original voronoi diagram]

To visualize the effects of the two "degrees of freedom" for this approach, I chose to visualize each combination of 4 different values for `alpha` (a, varying across columns) and `beta` (b, varying across rows) (32, 16, 8 and 4). The red dots show the points considered (effect of alpha), and the red line shows the boundary of the points used for the area calculation (effect of beta). The value p is percentage of the pixels that belong to the new point, and the value t is the time it took to compute the new point, in miliseconds. As you can see, the percentage is overall increasing as alpha and beta are decreased, as expected.

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=4, ncols=4, figsize=(8, 8))
for i, a in enumerate([32, 16, 8, 4]):
    for j, b in enumerate([32, 16, 8, 4]):
        start = time.time()
        xy = best_new_point(h, w, points, a, b)
        end = time.time()
        t = end - start
        points2 = points + [xy]
        img2 = draw_voronoi(h, w, points2)
        area = np.count_nonzero(img2 == len(points)) / (h * w)
        ax[j, i].imshow(img2);
        ax[j, i].scatter([y for x, y in points2], [x for x, y in points2], **{'c': 'black', 's': 12});
        grid_a = [(i, j) for i in range(0, h, a) for j in range(0, w, a)]
        ax[j, i].scatter([y for x, y in grid_a], [x for x, y in grid_a], c='red', s=0.25);
        grid_b = [(i, j) for i in range(0, h, b) for j in range(0, w, b)]
        pts = [(i, j) for i, j in grid_b if img2[i, j] == nd]
        hull = ConvexHull(pts)
        pts_arr = np.array(pts)
        for simplex in hull.simplices:
            ax[j, i].plot(pts_arr[simplex, 1], pts_arr[simplex, 0], 'r-')
        
        ax[j, i].set_xticks([])
        ax[j, i].set_yticks([])
        ax[j, i].set_title(f'a: {a}, b: {b}\np: {area*100:.2f}% t: {t*1000:.0f}ms')
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: comparison]